# Append values to JSON struct after creation

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I have created a JSON struct in Go. Here is my code where I create the struct, and add necessary values.

```
type Passport struct{
        MessageTopic string `json:"message_topic"`
        DeviceName string  `json:"device_name"`
        DeviceSchema string  `json:"device_schema"`
        DeviceID string  `json:"device_id"`
    }
    type sentData struct{
        Passport Passport `json:"passport"`
        IntegrationResult string `json:"integration_result"`
        ActionLog []string `json:"action_log"`
    }
response := sentData{
            Passport: Passport {
                MessageTopic: "handshake_reply",
                DeviceName: sensorConfig.Passport.DeviceName, //ignore
                DeviceSchema: sensorConfig.Passport.DeviceSchema, //ignore
                DeviceID: "",
            },
            IntegrationResult: "",
            ActionLog: []string{},
        }
        sensorReply, _ := json.Marshal(response)
```

I want to be able to add string elements to the `ActionLog` array. I do this by:

```
if sensorConfig.Passport.Interfaces.Wifi != "true" && sensorConfig.Passport.Interfaces.Wifi != "false" && sensorConfig.Passport.Interfaces.Wifi != "unknown"{
        fmt.Println("Wifi: incorrect option")
        response.ActionLog = append(response.ActionLog, "Wifi: incorrect option")
    }
fmt.Println(string(sensorReply))
```

This compiles, however when I print out the `sensorReply`, I get:

```
{"passport":{"message_topic":"handshake_reply","device_name":"My RPi","device_schema":"sensor/data","device_id":""},"integration_result":"","action_log":[]}
```

As you can see, the `action_log` field is empty. Is this the proper way to append values to a JSON?

Comment: In `append` use just `"your string"` not `string{"your string"}` as the second argument. Or just set the whole field without `append` like so: `response.ActionLog = []string{"Wifi: incorrect option"}`

Comment: If you need help with code that "cannot compile", *include the relevant compiler errors in your question*.

Comment: @mkopriva Check my recent edits. I tried your method but the field was empty when I printed it out.

Comment: @Ruby you Marshal the response value after you've set all values you want present in json, not before, once you marshal the response, the `sensorReply` and `response` value aren't "magically" connected. They are two separate values.

Comment: @mkopriva Ah, thank you. I am not familiar with Go, so that is a good point.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was just a matter of when to marshal the struct. Completed code below.

```
if sensorConfig.Passport.Interfaces.Wifi != "true" && sensorConfig.Passport.Interfaces.Wifi != "false" && sensorConfig.Passport.Interfaces.Wifi != "unknown"{
    fmt.Println("Wifi: incorrect option")
    response.ActionLog = append(response.ActionLog, "Wifi: incorrect option")
}
sensorReply, err := json.Marshal(response)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(sensorReply))
```